# Get slicer selection of a data table

Tags: excel, slicers, excel-tables

I have been struggling with this issue in the past days and haven't found yet any solution.

I have a simple `table` (not a `pivot table`) and some `slicers` attached to it. I want to 'simply' show selected value/values of the slicer in a cell. It implies of course to make the cell update automatically according to the selection.

Some of the solutions I found suggested using two pivot tables, one main for the regular data and the other hidden to capture the selected filters. The problem is that I am not working with a pivot table, but rather a simple table.

I also tried getting distinct values of the table column, but I couldn't perform it properly without getting the hidden values of the filtered table too.

Is there any way in Excel to do this simply?

Thank you!

[image: Tab]

Comment: You want to show the slicer in cells? Why? The slicer shows what you've chosen

Comment: I want to display it as a title

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to achieve your result

You will have to insert a serial number column in your table

[image]

After that insert the below formula above the header or anywhere you want to display the selected value

The formula in C2 is

```
=INDEX(Table1[Data 2],SUBTOTAL(5,Table1[S.No]))
```

Comment: thank you but it seems like it only get the first element, which is not good an enough of a solution if there are two values selected

Comment: For two values it can not be done in old excels, but in google sheets and office 365 there are solutions

Comment: @usmanhaq would you show how it can be done in Google Sheets then, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in your table with this

> =SUBTOTAL(103;[@Data2])=1

Put this formula where you want your list. It's a spill formula, so you only paste it in one cell, and it will spill to the cells below.

> =UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Data2];Table1[Visible]))

(Adjust for your local syntax)

[image]

Ideally I would want to nest these two formulas in order to avoid the extra column, but SUBTOTAL does not support that.

Beware that the table hides rows when you apply the slicer, and if you put the list next to the table they will be hidden as well.